# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un svg por medio del hover de otro elemento?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, transition

¡¡Hola a todos!!

He tenido una dificultad al crearle una transición de color a un svg cuando posiciono el cursor del ratón por encima del link. El resultado que busco es que el color del icono cambie cuando se pase el cursor por el link, pero con una transición. Muchas gracias a todos los que quieran ayudarme.

```css
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.elements-center svg {
    height: 25px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 25px;
}

.elements-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.elements-center a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-center">
  <h4>CONTACTO</h4>
  <div class="elements-center">
    <a href="#">
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 122.88 122.88"><title>email-round</title><path d="M61.44,0A61.46,61.46,0,1,1,18,18,61.21,61.21,0,0,1,61.44,0ZM32.22,79.39,52.1,59.46,32.22,43.25V79.39ZM54.29,61.24,33.79,81.79H88.91L69.33,61.24l-6.46,5.51h0a1.42,1.42,0,0,1-1.8,0l-6.78-5.53Zm17.18-1.82L90.66,79.55V43.07L71.47,59.42ZM34,41.09l27.9,22.76L88.65,41.09Zm65.4-17.64a53.72,53.72,0,1,0,15.74,38,53.56,53.56,0,0,0-15.74-38Z"/>
                            </svg>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <p id="email">nombre@correo.com</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando un poco [**este artículo**](https://www.paradigmadigital.com/dev/color-iconos-svg/), puedes cambiar de color al svg con la siguiente propiedad:

```
fill: red;
```

Y para que el cambio de color ocurra cuando pases el cursor por el link, colocamos la pseudo-clase [**`:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) de la siguiente forma:

```
.elements-center:hover svg {
  fill: red;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Adicionalmente, les agrego estas propiedades a tu link para que no tenga el color por defecto al haberle echo clic:

```
.elements-center a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.elements-center svg {
  height: 25px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 25px;
}

.elements-center:hover svg {
  fill: red;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.elements-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.elements-center a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-center">
  <h4>CONTACTO</h4>
  <div class="elements-center">
    <a href="#">
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 122.88 122.88"><title>email-round</title><path d="M61.44,0A61.46,61.46,0,1,1,18,18,61.21,61.21,0,0,1,61.44,0ZM32.22,79.39,52.1,59.46,32.22,43.25V79.39ZM54.29,61.24,33.79,81.79H88.91L69.33,61.24l-6.46,5.51h0a1.42,1.42,0,0,1-1.8,0l-6.78-5.53Zm17.18-1.82L90.66,79.55V43.07L71.47,59.42ZM34,41.09l27.9,22.76L88.65,41.09Zm65.4-17.64a53.72,53.72,0,1,0,15.74,38,53.56,53.56,0,0,0-15.74-38Z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <p id="email">nombre@correo.com</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```